# Убрать двойной клик по превью видео

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой html:

```
<div class="youtube"
 id="kSFa21iffmvy"
 data-params="modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&controls=1&vq=hd720">
 </div>
```

И такой jquery:

```
$(function() {
        $(".youtube").each(function() {
            // Зная идентификатор видео на YouTube, легко можно найти его миниатюру
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + this.id + '/sddefault.jpg)');

            // Добавляем иконку Play поверх миниатюры, чтобы было похоже на видеоплеер
            $(this).append($('<div/>', {'class': 'play'}));

            $(document).delegate('#'+this.id, 'click', function() {
                // создаем iframe со включенной опцией autoplay
                var iframe_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=1";
                if ($(this).data('params')) iframe_url+='&'+$(this).data('params');

                // Высота и ширина iframe должны быть такими же, как и у родительского блока
                var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {'frameborder': '0', 'src': iframe_url,'allowfullscreen':''})

                // Заменяем миниатюру HTML5 плеером с YouTube
                $(this).replaceWith(iframe);
            });
        });
    });
```

Суть вот в чем, на странице размещается несколько роликов с ютуба, я попытался ускорить время загрузки страницы, т.к. она грузилась довольно долго. Нашел такое решение, вместо iframe выводится сначала превьюшка видео. Но проблема в том, что при просмотре страницы с телефона приходится 2 раза кликать на видео,  один раз убирается превью, а второй клик запускает видео. На пк же все работает отлично, при первом клике картинка подменяется на Iframe  и видео запускается. Как исправить эту ситуацию, чтобы на телефоне не нужно было кликать по 2 раза?

Answer (score 0):

Q: YouTube Autoplay not working

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50272974/4794368

> It's not working since April of 2018 because Google decided to give greater control of playback to users. You just need to add &mute=1 to your URL. [Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

вольный перевод:

с апреля 2018 гугл изменила политику смотри [Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).
чтобы видео заработало просто добавь к URL `&mute=1`.

---

от переводчика:
на сколько я понимаю, теперь автозапуск видео только с выключенным звуком.

---

UPD:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50339171/4794368

> **However**, if you wish to enable **autoplay with sound** you should add `allow="autoplay"` to your embedded `<iframe>`.

```
<iframe type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-ePDPGXkvlw?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

Comment: Добавил параметр, звук выключен, но автозапуск не отрабатывает(

Comment: Да и на пк же срабатывает нормаль, почему-то

Comment: как вариант - на пк может быть старая версия браузера